ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trl'
I have installed trl using pip.
!pip show trl

and its showing packages info properly,
!pip show trl

Name: trl
Version: 0.7.10
Summary: Train transformer language models with reinforcement learning.
Home-page: https://github.com/huggingface/trl
Author: Leandro von Werra
Author-email: leandro.vonwerra@gmail.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages
Requires: accelerate, datasets, numpy, torch, transformers, tyro
Required-by: 

However, when I am importing in Notebook its showing error:
import trl

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 1
----> 1 import trl

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trl'

Why this discrepancy? How to resolve it?

The problem was solved when I installed from direct source using,
pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/trl.git

